# Json Image Passing to next Activity

Tags: android, json, gridview

I have the application to view json data into gridview(Images & Text) using Volley Library. Once I Click the Gridview the Image and Text Is pass to next activity
I can Use Gridview Adapter have to arraylist one for images and another text 
here is the Adapter

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
//Imageloader to load images
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
//Context
private Context context;

//Array List that would contain the urls and the titles for the images
private ArrayList<String> images;
private ArrayList<String> names;
public GridViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> images, ArrayList<String> names){
    //Getting all the values
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Creating a linear layout
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //HttpsURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
    //NetworkImageView
    NetworkImageView networkImageView = new NetworkImageView(context);
    //NetworkImageView networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView
           // .findViewById(R.id.gridimage);
    //Initializing ImageLoader
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(images.get(position), ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkImageView, R.drawable.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    //Setting the image url to load
    networkImageView.setImageUrl(images.get(position),imageLoader);

    //Creating a textview to show the title
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(names.get(position));

    //Scaling the imageview
    networkImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    networkImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));

    //Adding views to the layout
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(networkImageView);

    //Returnint the layout
    return linearLayout;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mFilter;
}
    }
```

Comment: And what seems to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Create onitemclick listener on activity for your gridview. Once the grid view item has been clicked you will get the position of the selected item. Get the selected image from your array list using selected position and pass via intent

Add this code inside your grid view item click listener

```
    String imageurl=yourimagestringarraylist.get(position)
String txt=yourtextstringarraylist.get(position)
Intent i= new intent(yourcurrentactivity.this,calling activity.class)
I.putExtra("imageurl",imageurl);
I.put extra("text",txt);
StartActivity(i);
```

Get the image and text from other activity by

```
String image=getIntent.getStringExtra("imageurl","");
String text= getIntent.getStringExtra("text","");
```

Comment: Where can i set image from the string image

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 way(simplest):
 1. Send text and img URL (in case if your image have big size)
 2. Send text and Bitmap (in case of small image). You can receive Bitmap form imageLoader callback loading

in your adapter:

```
    linearLayout.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
    void onClick() {
    Intent i = new Intent(convertView.getContext(), YourActivity.class);
    i.putString(key, text);
    i.putString(key, url); // if big img
    i.putSerialazible(key, bitmap); // if small image
     }
});
```

In another activity receive it:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(key);
(Bitmap)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(key);
```

Comment: How can i put image view based on this value. I can try but i can get Null pointer Exception

Comment: You can't put image view! You can get drawable from view(which you want put), getDrawable returns Bitmap, and Bitmap as serialized object can be putted to intent extras. In your case, just wait when imageLoader sets image to view, execute bitmap = imageView.getDrawable(). Than intent.putSerializable(bitmap)